# Create the Tag Wikis!

Tags: discussion, support, tags

In order to have a well worked out beta we need to understand the tags that we use. So, we need people to start creating [the wikis for the tags](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts). This will allow new users to better understand what to classify each question.

Comment: Tag wikis are not really a high priority, except for those tags where there may be some ambiguity. For example, there is no real urgency to creating a tag wiki for [norse], because everybody knows what sorts of questions merit a [norse] tag here.

Comment: @senshin: Not at the moment, no, but on Christianity.SE, we do have tag wikis for tags that the vast majority of people would know and understand. Just to clarify/pin them down.

Comment: One thing to be aware of when creating tag wikis or tag wiki excerpts - try to stay away from descriptions like "Fairy: for questions about fairies" (for example). This doesn't really add anything to the tag title, and can be improved on.

Comment: I would say at least the excepts are important early on to encourage a tagging convention, rather than a mish-mash of uses for any given tag.